# How to capture specific column values in a web table

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, web-testing

Looking for a solution to capture specific column values in a web table. to count no of eg-pass and fail count among captured column values and then print the counts for each status.

[image]

i want to directly go to the status column here and fetch all values under it. then want to get count of each status type and print.

Comment: Please update your question with code sample you've done so far and share URL or page source code.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this(if we are talking about html table):

```
   private List<WebElement> getTableRows(By by) {
        Validate.notNull(by, "Table element should not be null");
        List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElement(by).findElements(By.tagName("tr"));   // get table rows
        return rows;
    }

    protected String getCellValue(WebElement row, int columnIndex) {
        Validate.notNull(row, "Row element should not be null");
        String cell = "";
        cell = row.findElement(By.xpath("td[" + columnIndex + "]")).getText();  // get columns by index
        return cell;
    }
```